# Bind multiple styles from a computed object

Tags: knockout.js

I have a computed value which contains an amalgamation of other computed values which I then bind to my element:

**HTML**

```
<td data-bind="text: displayNamePipeJob, attr: primaryStyling()"></td>
```

**JS**

```
self.primaryStyling = window.ko.pureComputed(function()
{
    return {
        style: 'color: ' + self.primaryFontColor() + '; font-family: ' + self.fontFamily()
    }
});
```

To avoid the ugliness of building up a manual string in this fashion, is there some way to provide `style` as some kind of object with properties, for example:

```
self.primaryStyling = window.ko.pureComputed(function()
{
    return {
        style: {
            'color': self.primaryFontColor(),
            'font-family:': self.fontFamily()
        }
    }
});
```

Sadly this outputs to `style="[object Object]"`.

Comment: Use `data-bind="style: primaryStyling"` instead. The `style` binding accepts an object.

Answer (score 0):

One of the goals of knockout is separating your view from your model - returning the entire styling information directly from your model is therefore possibly not entirely correct.

I would approach it where the model contains effectively configuration information, and the view makes use of that.  Handily, knockout has a [`style` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html) for this purpose:

```
<td data-bind="text: displayNamePipeJob, style: {color: primaryColor, fontFamily: fontFamily }"></td>
```

If the values are calculated in a more complex fashion that your example here, you can build individual `computed` functions for each style attribute.